# Why Android put Fragments inside FrameLayouts?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-framelayout

Why Google usually put Fragments inside a FrameLayout. I see it in the examples and in the source code of the Google I/O App. I tried to translate the properties of the FrameLayout to the properties of the Fragment and all stayed equal as expected, so why do they use a FrameLayout container?

Comment: for compatibility with pre-fragment layouts i think.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because that way you can easily make it into a tabbed navigation, since [TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) extends FrameLayout, you can assign the FrameLayout resource to it.